# How can this function be simplified without using the conditional

Tags: regex, ruby

Fairly new to ruby so sorry if it's an easy solve.

I want to verify a 10 digit phone number regardless of formatting using Regex. The function contains a conditional however I think it can be simplified.

eg:

```
valid_phone = ["2438894546", "(718)891-1313", "234 435 9978", "(800)4261134"]

invalid_phone = ["28894546", "(718)891-13135", "234 43 9978"]

def valid_phone_number?(phone)
   number = phone.scan(/\d/)
   number.length == 10 ? true: false 
end
```

How do we count the arguments digits regardless of the special characters?

Comment: Nit: the ternary can be replaced by `number.length == 10`

Comment: Use `/\A\d{10}\z/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That won't match `"(718)891-1313"` correctly, as required...

Comment: You could first remove all non-digits, and then match `/^\d{10}$/`

Comment: You don't need the ternary there `phone.scan(/\d/).length == 10`

Comment: @vlumi `number.gsub(/\D+/, '')` and then a check against `/\A\d{10}\z/` will do. Or, `/\A(?:\D*\d){10}\D*\z/`

Comment: No regex: `def valid_phone_number?(phone);  phone.count("0-9") == 10 ; end`